# How can i copy a Extjs grid row

Tags: extjs

Hi i want to implement a copy feature so that i can right click and press copy  and paste in any wordpad , or something like this can any body give me a guidance how to implement this.
imagine it as simple grid. with many rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [here](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/03/extjs-copy-gridpanel-content-to-clipboard) is the perfect solution see it without flash

Comment: same blog [cross browser approach to copy content to clipboard with javascript](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/03/cross-browser-approach-to-copy-content-to-clipboard-with-javascript) downside: it uses flash

Comment: Does this also apply to Extjs 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at  [how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

to figure out how to do a cross browser clipboard copy first.

Then you can look into Extjs RowSelectionModel class http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/ which defines a rowselect event and rowselected method to return the record selected by user then pass it to the clipboard. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are two extensions for copy/paste actions on Grid Panels :

[Excel Editor Grid](http://www.developerextensions.com/index.php/extjs-excel-copypaste-grid?tmpl=demo)

and another [useful one](http://www.crp.de/Shared/extjs/examples/copyPasteExample/copyPasteExample.html)

If you want to use copy/paste in a general way, not only in grid panels you must use the Flash option.